# C# Printing ITF Barcode

Tags: c#, printing, barcode

I have created a c# win form application that generates ITF barcode.

I have a zebra TTP2130 printer I would like to print to.

I have read much on the topic just doesnt seem to be an easy way to print.

Thought Id check with you if anyone knows a simple way and has a clean solution for doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with iTextSharp (open source). There's an example here:http://itextsharp.sourceforge.net/examples/Chap0907.cs

And an explanation here:http://itextsharp.sourceforge.net/tutorial/ch09.html#barcode

Hope it will help you.